# how can I store data from div tag to database?

Tags: php, html, tooltip

I need to insert a div value into my database, as you can see down there in the code each seat inside div, so I have used hidden input for each div seat and I've given the same name for all input but they have different values to store it in the database the issue is it is only stored the last seat even if you selected the first seat.[this is the seating plan created by CSS, js, tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMQX8.png)

```html
      <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="plan">
          <h3 class="plan__title">Seating Plan</h3>
          <div class="rows rows--mini">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="B1">
                <input type="hidden" name="seat" value="B1"></div>
              <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="B2">
                <input type="hidden" name="seat" value="B2"> </div>
              <div class="row__seat tooltip" data-tooltip="B3">
                <input type="hidden" name="seat" value="B3"></div>

              <input type="submit" name="save" value="submit">
            </div>
            <!-- /plan -->
      </form>
```

```html
  <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="movieDb";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$db_name);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else{
        
    }


    if (isset($_POST['save'] )&& !empty($_POST['save']))

    {
        $seat=$_POST['seat'];
        if (!(empty($seat) ))
        {

            $var=new AddProduct();
            $var->productAdd($conn);
        }
    }
    else{

    }
    ?>

    <?php 
    class AddProduct{
        public function productAdd($conn)
        {
            $sql="insert into seates(sn) values(?);";

            if(($stmt=$conn->prepare($sql))) {
                $stmt->bind_param("s",$seat);

            }else
            {
                var_dump($conn->error);
            }
            $seat=$_POST['seat'];
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $_SESSION['msg']="Theater Successfully  Added";
            header ("Location: index.php" );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: why are you using the same name for all the three input fields? change their name. or use a select box.

Comment: Name your fields `name="seat[]"`, then you will get an array in `$_POST['seat']` that you can loop over.

Comment: @04FS could you please explain a bit more because I'm stuck at seat number.   Thank you^_^

Answer (score -1):

U have given same `name` for each div and sending all input value on form submit. So it will only take last value i.e., B3 , So I would suggest give diffrent id's to each div and then use javascript to make Ajax call with that particular value.